# Source Tree How to Pull?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Source Tree for my C# Monogame project and watched few tutorials how to setup and push files.

Once I forgott to save my project but had it pushed to bitbucket. Now I don't know how to pull these files, I tried the pull button but the project doesn't refresh in Visual Studio and I'm missing some classes.

How can I pull these files?

Answer (score 0):

In sourcetree after checkout the branch from the remotes folder to branches-->goto branches and select the particular branch which you want to pull the code from remote right click -->and select the option pull.